# Drawing image with an angle

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, xna-4.0

Edit: the images below aren't supposed to have whitespace. I am just trying to show you that i am trying to create a rectangle from a 1x64 image, positioned as shown in the second picture

I know how to rotate an image like that in XNA

[image: 2]

But how is it possible to draw a sprite in this angle this way ?

[image: 2]

I can't seem to be able to find an answer on that and i'm sort on ideas

Comment: so you wish to have isometric look of rectangle? hm... you have to move each column up in image. first column 0px, second column 1px, third 2px... there is no existing funciton for that, you will have to write it.

Comment: @DavorMlinaric that would mean that if i want to make a 200 width rectangle i would have to calculate 200 columns and then draw them separately , there has to be some kind of projection function that does that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Matrix CreateSkewY(float angle)
{
    Matrix skew = Matrix.Identity;
    skew.M21 = (float)Math.Tan((double)angle);
    return skew;
}

spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, null, null, null, null,
CreateSkewX((float)Math.PI / 6));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this example using matrix, but i didn't test it.

```
Matrix matrix = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(60)) * 
                Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(30)) * 
                Matrix.CreateScale(1,1,0);

spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, null, null, null, null, matrix);
```

Comment: i will check it and let you know how it went, thank you for the answer, if you have the link of the site where you got this example, it could possibly be useful to me if you can link it

Comment: it doesn't change anything at all on the screen, its strange

Comment: try looking for skew using matrix around. i realy can't help you more as i never tried something like this. if you found a solution post it here so other can also found it.